# Return just single Object instead of Array in NEXT.JS and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, next.js

How can i return single object for instead of array? Because i asking in api just for single "Event" I using MongoDB + Next.js

I always getting

[{}]

i Just want it get

{}

```
const fetchWithId = (url: RequestInfo) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json());

const index = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    `http://localhost:3000/api/events/event?slug=${router.query.slug}`,
    fetchWithId
  );
```

Here is a Next API

```
const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const {
    method,
     query: { slug},
  } = req;

  if (req.method !== 'GET') {
    return;
  }



  await dbConnect();

  const selectedEvent = await Events.find({
    slug: slug,
  });

  res.status(200).json(selectedEvent);
};



export default handler;
```

Comment: Short answer: `res.status(200).json(selectedEvent[0])`

Comment: Short, simple and right answer. Thanks Lucas... I thought here is a some function from mongoose..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to call the method [.findOne() rather than .find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/retrieve/):

```js
const selectedEvent = await Events.findOne({
    slug: slug
});
```

Comment: Thanks code_monk this is exactly what i looked for...